# User CoreData Relationship for Table data

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have a managedobject that has a to-many association on it. I want to use a collection of managed objects for the sections in my table, and then the association for the rows. The problem is the association is an NSSet so in cellForRowAtIndexPath: I can't reliably get the position of the sub object I want using the indexPath.row. Has anyone overcome this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an `NSFetchedResultsController`. It uses *sort descriptors* to display the
objects in a well-defined order, and with the `sectionNameKeyPath:` parameter it 
can group the objects automatically into sections.

In addition, it updates the table view automatically if objects are inserted, deleted or
changed.

Comment: Good suggestion. I'm using MagicalRecord, so I might try to use its internal FRC or just skip it on this Controller.